# How to add timeout test case fail in TestNg and Allure reporting framework?

Tags: selenium, testng, allure

Not able to write Allure test result if I use following timeout in `TestNG.xml` and methods.

```
<test name="TestName" time-out="60000">
        <classes>
            <class name="ClassName">
                <methods><include name="MethodName"></include>
                </methods>
            </class>
        </classes>
    </test>
```

OR

`@Test (timeOut = 10*60000)`

**Exception:
io.qameta.allure.AllureResultsWriteException: Could not write Allure test result
Caused by: java.nio.channels.ClosedByInterruptException**

Listener I used:

```
public class AllureListener implements IHookable {

    @Override
    public void run(IHookCallBack callBack, ITestResult testResult) {

        callBack.runTestMethod(testResult);
        if (testResult.getThrowable() != null || testResult.getStatus() == ITestResult.FAILURE
                || testResult.getStatus() == ITestResult.SKIP
                || testResult.getStatus() == ITestResult.SUCCESS_PERCENTAGE_FAILURE
                || testResult.getStatus() == ITestResult.SUCCESS_PERCENTAGE_FAILURE) {
            String methodName = testResult.getName().toString().trim();
            ITestContext context = testResult.getTestContext();
            WebDriver driver = (WebDriver) context.getAttribute("driver");
            if (driver != null) {
                AllureReportUtil ru = new AllureReportUtil();
                ru.addAttachment(driver, methodName);
            }
        }
}
```

Kindly help me in this.

Comment: what version of allure-testng are you using? Seems like this issue should be fixed in latest versions

Comment: Allure version:  <artifactId>allure-testng</artifactId>

<version>2.0-BETA14</version>

Comment: try to upgrade to 2.8.1